# Code to copy/paste columns

Tags: excel

I want to write VBA code for daily work in Excel. There is a function:

`VLOOKUP(C2,DetailedView!C:AI,16,false)`

which searches for values to update the Excel sheet.

Also there are steps like copy-paste columns.

How can I convert these steps into Excel VBA?

Comment: [Step 1 - Start with the macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Step-1-Start-with-the-macro-recorder-6DC53056-1DE1-4483-AA07-63E4E0EFE3C2).

Answer (score -1):

Do you really want this being a macro? What about displaying the values of other cells instead of copy / paste?

If you just want to see the content of one `source cell` in some other `target cell`, then just refer ot the `source cell` within the `target cell` by entering `=<coordinates of the source cell>` into the `target cell`.

Example:
Source cell coordinates: `A1`
Source cell content: `foo`
Target cell content: `=A1`
Target cell displays: `foo`